# Как сделать изменение размера Iframe  в зависимости от изменения размера окна в IE?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте.

Написала скрипт, чтобы размер плавающего окна менялся от события OnResize окна родительского. В Опере, Мазилле все работает. В IE iframe остается маленьким, как ни дергай браузер за уголок. Скрипт такой:

```
<script language="JavaScript">          
function load1Fram() {
    var hh = window.innerWidth;
    var ww = window.innerWidth;
    var frim = document.getElementById("ifr");
    frim.height = hh * 0.9
    frim.width = ww * 0.9
}
load1Fram()     
</script>
```

При распечатке промежуточных результатов, выяснилось, что IE не воспринимает свойства innerWidth и innerHeight. Попытка заменить их просто на height и width тоже ни к чему не привела. Скрипт работает, с вариантом screenHeight, но мне нужно, чтобы размер iframe менялся пропорционально окну броузера. Расскажите, пожалуйста, как быть.

Answer (score 2):

1. Наверное, очепятка, но должно быть

```
var hh = window.innerHeight;
var ww = window.innerWidth;
```

2. window.innerHeight и window.innerWidth поддерживаются IE, но только начиная с версии 9.0

3. Решение: возлюби объект document.body (:

```
function load1Fram( )
  {
    var h = document.body.scrollHeight > document.body.offsetHeight ?
      document.body.scrollHeight : document.body.offsetHeight ;
    var w = document.body.scrollWidth > document.body.offsetWidth ?
      document.body.scrollWidth : document.body.offsetWidtn ;
    var frim = document.getElementById("ifr") ;
    frim.height = h * 0.9 ;
    frim.width = w * 0.9
  }
load1Fram( )
```

PS. Но помни, Золушка: после 12 удара часов твой тампакс превратится в тыкву, а до срабатывания события window.onload document.body может быть null

Comment: Большое спасибо, все работает.